# Rac installation nslookup finds the ip address but fails

Tags: networking, nameserver, nslookup

I have installed dnsmasq on my linux rac instance. While trying nslookup it finds all the 3 scan ip address but at the end it says

```
**** server can't find ol7-orcl19c-scan: REFUSED.**
```

Given below are nslookup and nslookup debug info. Please let me know how to proceed from this error.

```
[root@ol7-orcl19c-rac1 rpm]# nslookup  ol7-orcl19c-scan
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.15
Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.12
Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.14
**** server can't find ol7-orcl19c-scan: REFUSED**
```

Given below is the **nslookup with **DEBUG**** info for the same

```
[root@ol7-orcl19c-rac1 rpm]# nslookup -debug ol7-orcl19c-scan
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    ol7-orcl19c-scan, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  ol7-orcl19c-scan
    internet address = 192.168.1.14
    ttl = 0
    ->  ol7-orcl19c-scan
    internet address = 192.168.1.15
    ttl = 0
    ->  ol7-orcl19c-scan
    internet address = 192.168.1.12
    ttl = 0
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.14
Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.15
Name:   ol7-orcl19c-scan
Address: 192.168.1.12
------------
    QUESTIONS:
    ol7-orcl19c-scan, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
**** server can't find ol7-orcl19c-scan: REFUSED**
```

Comment: When there are only three hosts, set them as static in the host file; otherwise, a domain is needed so that the resolve will have a target to fetch.